# In which situation do we choose randomized binary search instead of the normal binary search?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, binary-search, searching

Both randomized and normal binary search takes O(log n) time complexity but why does the randomized version exist? In other words what is the advantage of randomized binary search even if it has same time complexity like that of the original binary search ?

Comment: When you say "time complexity", do you mean worst-case or average-case complexity? Usually we take the former for deterministic and the latter for randomized algorithms.

Comment: worst case time complexity !!

Comment: Are you sure about O(log n)? If you are referring to randomized binary search as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471924/randomized-binary-search-algorithm) or [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/randomized-binary-search-algorithm/) (i.e., iteratively picking a random element in the interval's range instead of its middle), then the worst-case complexity is *definitely not* O(log n).

Comment: oops sorry its about average case in which both normal binary and randomized binary have same time complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Randomized binary search makes sense if your randomness source has a good bias towards your search target. You can then use it to reduce the expected search time (even retaining the $O(\log n)$ asymptotic worst-case complexity) as described in [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/43836/45242).

If your randomness source is simply a uniform distribution, then you won't get much out of it. If you use it naively (i.e., simply choosing the midpoint according to your randomness source), it will actually perform *worse* than standard binary search since the worst-case complexity will be $O(n)$, not $O(\log n)$ (consider the case where your interval is $[1,n]$, your target 1, and your randomness source outputs $n-1, n-2, n-3, \dots$).

Comment: thnks ..............

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you believe this answers your question, don't forget to click the tick mark to the left and mark it as an "accepted" answer  :)